# List folders in a project (Eclipse RCP)

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

Given a folder name I need to retrieve all its sub folders (just the sub folders that are right under the given folder, not the sub sub folders), I'm using `IResource` to identify if the resource is a folder or not, but I'm still trying to get a list of all the resources and then identify if is a folder or not using the code I already have, so the question is, is there a way to list all the resources in a given folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the `IResource` at hand is a folder, you can cast it to `IContainer`.
Then you can call `members()` to obtain all its children. By evaluating the `getType()` method of each member, you can determine if it is a (sub-)folder.